# WCF: How to change the settings of <GenerateMessageContracts>true</GenerateMessageContracts> - PHP client

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

.NET Client while consuming the WCF service I am able to change **GenerateMessageContracts** settings manually here.

File: **Reference.svcmap**

```
<ReferenceGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="c3e3cd74-61c2-408a-a511-63a2b654abd3"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-wcfservicemap">
 <ClientOptions>
    …………
   <GenerateMessageContracts>true</GenerateMessageContracts>
 </ClientOptions>
</ReferenceGroup>
```

I would like to change these setting in the WCF Service itself.

Dont know how to set **GenerateMessageContracts**  manually for PHP client.

Anybody knows this?

Comment: this can be configured when adding a service in visual studio by checking 'generate message contract'. Isn't there any way to do that in PHP while adding service reference?

Comment: Vibhu, I dont know how to achieve in php?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change that setting on the server side. The metadata exposed by the service (WSDL) which is consumed by the client side does not have any information regarding message contracts - that's a WCF term, while WSDL is a general-purpose standard. You can have two clients, one with message contracts, and one without, which send exactly the same request (and accepts the same response) to the service, and as far as the service is concerned, the requests are identical.

Comment: one with message contract how to specify in the client?

Comment: Does the PHP client have a concept of message contract?